# Is it a good idea to cache DataContractSerializer instances?

Tags: caching, windows-services, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I'm writing a windows service application that needs to serialize and deserialize XML documents repeatedly during its execution. As I need to serialize and deserialize generic types that are not known during compilation time (I don't know a priori how many types I need to serialize/deserialize) I'd like to know if it is a good idea do keep a cache of DataContractSerializer objects I instantiate for serializing and deserializing the objects.

I'm asking this question because I know it is a good idea to cache the XmlSerializer class instances since they create a dynamic assembly in memory under the hood and the assemblies dynamically created in memory are not garbage collected.

I read that the DataContractSerializer relies on lightweight code generation, but I'm not usual with the details of it. That is why I'm asking this question, I need to understand if I instantiate DataContractSerializer instances as needed it would lead me to a memory leak as the XmlSerializer would?

I have chose to use the DataContractSerializer instead of the XmlSerializer for being able to serialize internal properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...it is a good idea to cache the XmlSerializer class instances since they create a dynamic assembly in memory under the hood...

With `XmlSerializer`, it actually depends on whether you use the *simple* constructor (`new XmlSerializer(typeToHandle)`), or the more complex constructors that allow you to specify all the attributes etc at runtime. If you only use the simple constructor it re-uses the background assembly, so there is no repeat penalty.

I would *expect* (but haven't tested) `DataContractSerializer` to work similarly; but there is certainly no harm in simply caching it, perhaps in a static readonly field

Note that `DataContractSerializer` restricts the xml layout you have available to you... as long as you're OK with that ;-p

Comment: Do you know which restrictions are impost to the xml layout when using the DataContractSerializer? I'd like to know just to make sure I'm ok with that :P

Comment: There is no equivalent of [XmlAttribute], being the most obvious. If your main aim is to serialize data, it is fine (as are various others). If your main aim is to write xml in a specific layout, it can be troublesome.